# Upper bound for the sum of all absolute values of entries of arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

For any $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}=(A_{ij})$ with bounded operator norm, does the following inequality hold true?
$$
\left(\sum_{i,j} |A_{ij}|\right)^2 \leqslant n^2 \cdot \|\mathbf{A}\|_2^4,\tag{*}
$$
where $\|\mathbf{A}\|_2$ denote the operator norm of $\mathbf{A}$.

**My attempt:**

By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the norm inequality $\|\mathbf{A}\|_F \leqslant \sqrt{n}\cdot\|\mathbf{A}\|_2$, I get
$$
\left(\sum_{i,j} |A_{ij}|\right)^2 \leqslant n^2\cdot \sum_{ij} |A_{ij}|^2 = n^2\cdot \|\mathbf{A}\|_F^2 \leqslant n^3 \cdot \|\mathbf{A}\|_2^2.
$$
The notation $\|\mathbf{A}\|_F$ denotes the Frobenious norm of $\mathbf{A}$.

My upper bound $n^3\cdot \|\mathbf{A}\|$ is different from (*).

**Numerical simulation:**
I write `R` codes to conduct simulation:

```
n <- 100
for (i in 1:100) {
    A <- matrix(rnorm(n^2, 0, 1), n, n)
    A <- A%*%t(A)/n # ||A||_2 is bounded
    TF <- sum(abs(A))^2 < n^2 * norm(A, "2")^4
    cat(sprintf("Loop %d: %s\n", i, TF))
}
```

The simulation result confirms that (*) is true. But I don't know how to prove it.

**Update (2023-01-09):**

According to the counter-examples given in the comments below, the inequality (*) is **wrong** (though it appears in a published research paper).

Comment: Do you have some unmentioned assumptions on the norm of $A$?

Comment: @VezenBU $\mathbf{A}$ has bounded operator norm. I forgot to mention it. I have edited the problem. Thanks.

Comment: take $A=\mathrm{diag}(1/2,1/2,1/2).$ Then $(\sum_{i,j}^n\vert a_{ij}\vert)^2=\frac{9}{4}.$ And $n^2\Vert A\Vert_2^4=\frac{9}{16}.$

Comment: Consider $A=tI$. The LHS is a constant multiple of $t^2$ while the RHS is a constant multiple of $t^4$. Clearly the LHS is larger when $t$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: Agree! Thanks for your counter-examples.